# Php MongoDB Write a CSV File

Tags: php, mongodb

I have searched the internet, and could not get any specific details about it.

The environment is `Windows 8`, `WAMP` , `MONGODB`

I am trying to design a webpage, which have 4 fields: `Name,Contact,Device,Email.` After an user hits the `submit` button, the data inserts in the MongoDb. All this works fine.

The issue starts when I try to `write the inserted data in the csv file`, as this is the requirement. I have tried `MongoDB Export command in the cmd`, and it works fine, but trying to call the same using `exec function in the php script` is proving to be futile.

I have tried with this also, by storing the `command in a .bat` file, and then calling the .bat file using the php's exec function, still, no effect

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
exec("c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.3\conf\export.bat");

?>
```

I have enabled the checbox interaction with desktop in my WAMP server.

I don't need any specific help related with the coding, all I need is some direction on how to proceed ahead, as I know that I am missing something. Also, I reiterate, did not get anything specific on the Internet, hence, posting the question.

Kindly let me know on how to achieve this.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will dump your selected database to the a json file

```
$mongoExport = 'c:\mongodb\mongoexport'; //full path to mongoexport binary
$database = 'test';
$collection = 'foo';
$file = "c:\\temp\\foo.json"

exec(sprintf("%s -d %s -c %s -o %s",
    $mongoExport,
    $database,
    $collection,
    $file
));
```

And this is using pure PHP, for sure will be more fast the mongoexport option, with large collections:

```
$database = 'test';
$collection = 'foo';

$m = new MongoClient();
$col = $m->selectDB($database)->$collection;

$json = json_encode(iterator_to_array($col->find()));
```

Answer (score 3):

The following may work

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

$database   = "DATABASE";
$colName    = "COLLECTION";
$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->$colName->$database;

$cursor     = $collection->find();
foreach($cursor as $cur)
   echo '"'.$cur['field_1'].'","'.$cur['field_2']."\"\n";
```

Comment: This one is good but how can i go to next line for next record which is embedded that i am having in the same record retried from collection

Comment: Add ."\n" for new line at the end of the echo statement. Edited the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://Hostname:27017", array("replicaSet" => "rs0"));

if(!$conn){
    die("Unable to connect with mongodb");
}

$db = $conn-><DB NAME>; // DB name
$col1 = $db-><colname>;
$col2 = $db-><colname>; // collection name which u want .
$filterCountry = array("status"=>"1"); // where query
$records = $col1->find($filterCountry);


$fp= fopen('exampleTest11.csv', 'w'); // open csv file in which u want write data.

$headings[] = "Code";   
$headings[] = "Status" ; 
$headings[] = "EMP CODE";

fputcsv($fp, $headings);      // PUT Headings .
$cnt =0;     
foreach($records as $val)   {

    $csvarr = array();
    $csvarr['code']= $val['code'];  // fetch data from database.
    $csvarr['Status']= $val['status'];
    $csvarr['emp_code']= $val['emp_code'];

    fputcsv($fp, $csvarr);
    $cnt++;
}


echo "Completed Successfully..".$cnt;
```